# Writing values to Excel cells using C#

Tags: c#, excel, visual-studio-code, excel-interop, .net-core-2.0

I have a simple C# method written in Visual Studio Code that should create a new Excel workbook, write a value to a cell within a worksheet and then save the file.

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

namespace Test
{
    class ExcelTest
    {
        public void TestMethod()
        {
            String outputPath = "C:\\Test.xlsx";

            Excel.Application excel = new Excel.Application();
            Excel.Workbook workbook = excel.Workbooks.Add(Type.Missing);
            Excel.Worksheet sheet = (Excel.Worksheet)workbook.ActiveSheet;

            ((Excel.Range)sheet.Cells[1,1]).Value = "Hello";

            workbook.SaveAs(outputPath);
            workbook.Close();
            excel.Quit();
        }
    }
}
```

When calling this method, code execution stops on the ((Excel.Range)sheet.Cells[1,1]).Value = "Hello"; line with the following exception:

> Exception has occurred: CLR/System.NullReferenceException
>       An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

The method seems to be interacting with Excel as replacing the line with 'sheet.Name = "Test";' results in the file being saved and the workbook containing one sheet with the name 'Test'.

For reference I am using Visual Studio Code, and have Excel 2016 installed on my machine, and the .csproj file has the following references:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel" Version="*"/>
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Thanks

Comment: What is null? Is it sheet? Is it sheet.Cells? Is it sheet.Cells[1,1]?

Comment: That's odd - your code worked perfectly for me, so the code itself is not a problem. The reference in my project file is _"<Reference Include="Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c, processorArchitecture=MSIL">"_

Comment: shouldn't it be `Cells[1,"A"]` ?

Comment: I believe it is 'sheet.Cells[1,1]' which is null, as I can reference 'sheet.Name' and change that, and also get 'sheet.Cells.Count' which returns a value of 0.

Comment: Have you tried making the Application visible _(excel.Visible = true;)_  to see what the worksheet looks like & whether you can manually type into cell A1. My other thought is possibly a permissions issue - you may not have authority to create files in the root directory - try creating it in a folder you know you have write permission (e.g. Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments)

Comment: Hi Paul, just followed your advice and added the line to make it visible. The Excel 2016 application started and I was able to manually enter data into the cells whilst the program was in break mode. The file then saved successfully using the C# code, so the rest of the code seems to working as intended.

Comment: At least after changing the path to a place where the program has write rights the code runs fine. (Never write into the system root folder!!) And, no excel doesn't need to open.

Comment: The sheet.Cells.Count being 0 seems a bit odd - I have tested your code several times now & it works everytime. Check you have added the correct Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel reference to the project - I get the options of both version 14.0.0.0 & 15.0.0.0 - your code works with both of those for me. Also check you are building for a suitable .Net version.

Comment: As for the comment on the root directory, I have been using a different folder where the program has write permissions. The file path was just simplified for posting here to remove personal information.

Comment: I tested your code as is - writing to the root directory & it worked, though I know with some setups that is a problem.

Comment: Hi Paul, apologies if this is my fault for setting it up incorrectly, I'm new to C# and .NET. The reference to Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel seems fine, I still get the same issue with 14.0.0.0 and the latest version 15.0.4795.1000. Although when I run 'dotnet restore' I get the warning: _"warning NU1701: Package 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel 15.0.4795.1000' was restored using '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1' instead of the project target framework '.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.0'. This package may not be fully compatible with your project."_ Do I need to change the .NET version I am using?

Comment: Check the project properties - you may have an option in there - I am not familiar with Visual Studio Code but if it is similar to Visual Studio the Target Framework is an option that can be selected on the Application tab.

Comment: @Tom, ok but don't complicate matters by modifying the real code too much. Changing the drive letter would have been enough. - As for the real problem, I really can't reproduce. I am referencing MS Excel 10&14 Object Library on VS15 com. Any other modifications ?-)

Comment: I don't know if it is relevant but I have not installed any addition interop package using NuGet to my project. I just added the existing reference available in "Add Reference" from the project explorer. Unfortunately I have to leave now, so cannot try to be of further help until after the weekend. Best of luck.

Comment: I'd load up the code above with Console.Writelines.  Without them there are a number of assumptions, like: "ActiveSheet" (which one is the program really reading (i know you mentioned you'd done this already but it doesn't hurt to console.writeline it)), sheet count (just to see if it can read the sheet count), etc.  Then I'd try reading a value or just doing that in the immediate window, trying different variations until it can successfully read a cell.  After you've added the console.writelines, post the results.  Perhaps even give a screenshot of the excel sheet with tabs/row/columns.

Comment: Do you use .Net Core?

Comment: @TaW It is a .Net Core application with the Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel package installed with NuGet.

Comment: It is essential to add that as a Tag to each question.

Comment: I have just tried starting a new project with a .NET Framework application rather than a .NET Core application. I added references to the Microsoft Excel 16 Object Library and installed the interop package with NuGet. The program now successfully writes to cells and saves the file with the code in the original question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For reference I fixed this by rebuilding the application as a .NET Framework application rather than a .NET Core application. The COM interop functionality worked after doing this.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried just as:

```
sheet.Cells[1,1].Value = "Hello";
```

I don't think it needs to be cast as a range object to set the value.

Comment: I have tried this and Visual Studio gives the error "_'object' does not contain a definition for 'Value' and no extension method 'Value' accepting a first argument of type 'object' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)_"